# Use Regex to find and delete a string - but leave the last character

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find the "strPattern" string below, but use REPLACE to replace only "strPattern1" - which is effectively "strPattern" excluding the last character.

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "^\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}\s\OS\s[MCVH]"

Dim strPattern1 As String: strPattern1 = "^\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}\s\OS"

Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strInput As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("B1", Range("b1").End(xlDown))

For Each cell In Myrange
    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = cell.Value

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            cell.Offset(0, 0) = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fields in your search string '()'. e.g. "(^\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}\s\OS\s)([MCVH])".  Your replace string would be "$2".

Comment: thank you that seemed to work - except I replaced with "$2" instead. Thanks!

Comment: Correct.  I always mix up word find/replace field numbering and regex field numbering.